# tcl command for removing a word mutilple times

Tags: command, tcl

I want to convert .v file to .VHD ,so there are many lines of `assign` statements .want to delete all assign words. so is there any TCL command for that   ,am using VIVADO 2018.2.

For example, I have this input text:

```
assign mem[0]=4b'0000; 
assign mem[1]=4'b0001;
.................
assign mem[511]=4'b1010;
```

I want to delete all `assign` words at a time because to convert .V file to .VHDL

Comment: Could you give a sample of your input and expected output?

I suspect the `string map` command might be helpful - see https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M34

Comment: The two possibilities for solving this are likely to be `string map` and `regsub -all`. The correct choice will depend on the details.

Comment: assign mem[0]=4b'0000; assign mem[1]=4'b0001;.................assign mem[511]=4'b1010;.  so i want to delete all assign words at a time because to convert .V file to  .VHDL

Comment: Please add those details to the question so they can be correctly formatted. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, we are looking to specifically delete a word and not just the sequence of characters `assign` (because who knows where else that might come up?) The right tool for this is to use the `regsub` command so that we can specify that we want word boundaries to be matched:

```
set content [regsub -all {\yassign\y} $content ""]
```

The `\y` in there [matches a word boundary](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M76). Just what we need! (Replacing with the empty string is an obvious way to delete things.)

To turn this into a full conversion, we need to add in the code to read in the file and write it back out again.

```
set filename_in "something.V"
set filename_out "something.vhdl"

# Standard pattern for reading a whole file
set f [open $filename_in]
set content [read $f]
close $f

set content [regsub -all {\yassign\y} $content ""]

# Standard pattern for writing a whole file
set f [open $filename_out "w"]
puts -nonewline $f $content
close $f
```

The `-nonewline` is because when we read in the content, we kept all the line separators and our transform hasn't touched them. Wwe don't want to add any bonus ones at the end; that can get annoying if you're doing many transformations on a file.

---

If the file is very large, it can help a lot to process things a bit at a time. That's easy in this case because we are not trying to do a multi-line match.

```
set filename_in "something.V"
set filename_out "something.vhdl"

set f_in [open $filename_in]
set f_out [open $filename_out "w"]
while {[gets $f_in line] >= 0} {
    set line [regsub -all {\yassign\y} $line ""]
    puts $f_out $line
}
close $f_in
close $f_out
```

Note that this pattern *can't* write back to the same file.